# Очень простой скрипт отказывается работать в ИЕ

Tags: javascript

```
function oknoblock(el) {
var els = window.document.getElementsByClassName('okno');
for (var i=0; i<els.length; ++i) {els[i].style.display='none';};
el.firstElementChild.style.display='block';
};
```

Ие 8 пишет:
Объект не поддерживает это свойство или метод. Строка 2 символ 1.

В HTML функция вызывается вот так:
    <div id="n1" onclick="oknoblock(this)">

Answer (score 2):

```
// "getElementsByClassName" не определен IE, 
// так что этот метод можно реализовать в JavaScript 
if(document.getElementsByClassName == undefined) { 
   document.getElementsByClassName = function(cl) { 
      var retnode = []; 
      var myclass = new RegExp('\\b'+cl+'\\b'); 
      var elem = this.getElementsByTagName('*'); 
      for (var i = 0; i < elem.length; i++) { 
         var classes = elem[i].className; 
         if (myclass.test(classes)) { 
            retnode.push(elem[i]); 
         } 
      } 
      return retnode; 
   } 
};
```

Взято из: http://web.izjum.com/getelementsbyclassname-on-javascript

Comment: вторую строчку прошел, большое спасибо... теперь
firstElementChild.style есть null или не является объектом в том же ИЕ 8... непобедимый он какой-то

Comment: Все просто. Нет у IE такого свойства.

    (el.firstElementChild || el.children[0] || el.firstChild || {}).style.display = 'none';

Вроде такая запись должна работать везде. Хотя последнее `{}` бессмысленно ставить в данном случае...

Comment: Но ведь hildren[0] может возвратить не только тэг но и текстовый узел и firstChild так же! А @ustal хочет получать именно ТЭГ!

Answer (score 1):

Вместо firstElementChild в IE<9 используйте:

```
var node = this.firstChild,
    firstElementChild = null;

for ( ; node; node = node.nextSibling) {
    if (node.nodeType === 1) {
        firstElementChild = node;
        break;
    }
}
```

в `firstElementChild` окажется первый тэг

Взято с сайта [stack overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6333249/firstelementchild-doesnt-work-in-internet-explorer-7-what-are-my-options)