# В ие не передается значение this

Tags: javascript

<div id="n1" onclick="oknoblock(this)">

```
function oknoblock(el) {
alert(el);
el.firstElementChild.style.display='block';
```

В ИЕ 8 пишет, что firstElementChild null или не является объектом, в остальных браузерах все работает нормально.

alert в ие 8 выдает просто [object]... остальные браузеры [object HTMLDivElement]

Как передать this чтобы его ИЕ 8 прососал?

Comment: Просто скопируйте код 

   function oknoblock(el){
     var node = window.event?event.srcElement:el;
      firstElementChild = null;

   for ( ; node; node = node.nextSibling) {
        if (node.nodeType === 1) {
            firstElementChild = node;
            break;
        }
    }
      alert(node);
      firstElementChild.style.display='block';
    }

и ничего не изменяйте! Протестировано работает!

Comment: А в каких браузерах присходила ошибка?

Answer (score 1):

> В браузерах, IE<9,
>   существует свойство
>   `window.event.srcElement`, аналогичное `this`.

Цитата с [learn.javascript.ru](http://learn.javascript.ru/)

***UPD***:

```
<div id="n1" onclick="oknoblock(this)">

function oknoblock(el){
 var node = window.event?event.srcElement:el;
    firstElementChild = null;

for ( ; node; node = node.nextSibling) {
    if (node.nodeType === 1) {
        firstElementChild = node;
        break;
    }
}
  alert(node);
  firstElementChild.style.display='block';
}
```

***UPD 2***
Как мною уже было сказано на [ХэшКод](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/113265/%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%8C-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D1%81%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BF%D1%82-%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%B7%D1%8B%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B2-%D0%B8%D0%B5):

Вместо firstElementChild в IE<9 используйте:

```
var node = this.firstChild,
    firstElementChild = null;

for ( ; node; node = node.nextSibling) {
    if (node.nodeType === 1) {
        firstElementChild = node;
        break;
    }
}
```

в `firstElementChild` окажется первый тэг

Взято с сайта stack overflow

Comment: Вот... дополнил

Comment: Всё поправил ато с  C++  пока на Js переключишся.. всё надо вспоминать

Comment: Так вам же было сказано мной посмотрите мой UPD 2  к ответу

Comment: как будет выглядеть функция? я уже все... склеился

Comment: Вот конечный код в upd посмотрите

Comment: function oknoblock(el) {
var node = this.firstChild,
    firstElementChild = null;

for ( ; node; node = node.nextSibling) {
    if (node.nodeType === 1) {
        firstElementChild = node;
        break;
    }
}
  alert(firstElementChild);
  firstElementChild.style.display='block';
};

теперь все браузеры выдают NULL через alert 
(отформатировать не получается)